# OAuth2 Dropwizard (server) and jQuery / Ajax (client) example

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, dropwizard

I have scoured the internet and cannot find a good example to get started with a simple SPA that authenticates via an ajax POST to my dropwizard rest api. The doc on the site around authorisation is quite limited so I have no idea how to get started. Ideally I would like to authenticate, and receive a token in my client that I can then use to access other functions in my api. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2):

I found this example useful when implementing OAuth2 with Dropwizard: https://github.com/remmelt/dropwizard-oauth2-provider

For posting data with JQuery to the backend service you can refer to the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Thanks for the comment :) This looks very promising. Don't know how I didn't find it when I was tirelessly researching this!! I will let you know how I get on with it ;)

Comment: I am nearly there with the implementation. Have managed to get sessions set up on both sides. I just have one minor issue around the Authenticator in that example. I have implemented it in the same way as the example and have registered it in my application class. However, I am unsure how the authenticate method is supposed to be called. I have set a breakpoint and cannot find the place where it runs. This is the method where I have the logic for checking if the session has expired so my session actually never expires. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I read somewhere that the method gets triggered every time your session token is received from client-side via the 'Authorization' header in ajax beforeSend: but it still doesn't fire. No idea what to do now.

Comment: 1. run the example https://github.com/remmelt/dropwizard-oauth2-provider in your favourite Java IDE in debug mode so that you can set breakpoints where you wish 2. get tool such as https://code.google.com/p/rest-client/ for testing 3. restclient GET localhost:8080/ping -> pong 4. restclient POST localhost:8080/oauth2/token with form params [grant_type=password,username=alice,password=secret,client_id=1] -> 49556fdd-0807-4ca1-9e44-5d2d53466b8b 5. restclient GET localhost:8080/ping/auth [OAuth2 bearer token=49556fdd-0807-4ca1-9e44-5d2d53466b8b] -> "authenticated pong for user 1"